# Pandas: Adding a new column and values with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe: df1, B column values are list in a list

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aa', 'bb'], 
                'B': [[[1,'cc'],[2,'aa']],[[3,'dd'],[4,'bb']]], 
                'ADDED': [10, 20]})
```

and dataframe: df2

```
df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                     'number': [55, 66, 77, 88]})
```

I am trying to do string matching on column A and B

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for i,val in enumerate(df1['A'].values):
   for val2 in df1['B'][i]:
       score = fuzz.partial_ratio(val, val2)
       if score > 99:
           df3 = df3.append(df2.loc[df2['id'] == val2[0], 'number'])
```

My result looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'1': [66, 'NaN'], '3': ['NaN', 66]}, index=['number', 'number'])
```

Is there anyway to do this in an efficient way and the result would look like this: (added additional column from df1)

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'number': [66, 88], 'ADDED': [10, 20]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using explode will allow you to look at each sub list without iteration over it.  Then you can use the fuzzy match to filter the df1 and use `join` which defaults to joining on index to get your results.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aa', 'bb'], 
                'B': [[[1,'cc'],[2,'aa']],[[3,'dd'],[4,'bb']]], 
                'ADDED': [10, 20]})

df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3,4], 'number': [55, 66, 77, 88]})

df1 = df1.explode('B')
# Rowwise fuzzy match
df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['A'], x['B'][1]) > 99, axis=1)]

df2[['number']].join(df1[['ADDED']], how='inner')
```

Output

```
    number  ADDED
0       55     10
1       66     20
```

Comment: Using `explode` was a brilliant move. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work for me:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aa', 'bb'], 
            'B': [[[1,'cc'],[2,'aa']],[[3,'dd'],[4,'bb']]], 
            'ADDED': [10, 20]})
df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'number': [55, 66, 77, 88]})
df1 = df1.explode('B')
df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['A'], x['B'][1]) > 99, 
       axis=1)]
df1['number'] = df1['B'].apply(lambda x: df2.loc[df2['id']==x[0], 
                'number'].values[0])
```

Output:

```
df1
    A        B  ADDED  number
0  aa  [2, aa]     10      66
1  bb  [4, bb]     20      88
```

Thank you, Chris.